# Nuxt - dynamic params after building does not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In a Nuxt ("spa" mode) project I have a url with a dynamic param `/shop/:product`, which can be as such:

```html
    /shop/ipad-128gb-rose-gold
    /shop/subway-gift-card
    /shop/any-string
```

etc.

Using this directory structure works fine in development environment:

```
pages/
  shop/
    _product.vue
```

However it does not work in production. Looking to the generated `bin/` folder I see that there is nothing inside `shop/` directory. And I see that Nuxt mentions a solution here: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/#routes

But in my situation, I don't know what the `:product` param will be (could be any string).

I am fetching the `product` details in `pages/shop/_product.vue` from the server (if it exists), otherwise handling the error. So now how do I do that in a production build?

I think I am misunderstanding the Nuxt solution -- am I really supposed to generate *all* possible routes for every existing product slug??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for me was to use:

```js
// nuxt.config.js

export default {
  ...
  generate: {
    fallback: true
  }
}
```

I am serving the app out of the built `dist/` folder. And I came across this in the Netlify deployment docs:

> For a single page app there is a problem with refresh as by default on
> netlify the site redirects to *"404 not found"*. For any pages that
> are not generated they will fallback to SPA mode and then if you
> refresh or share that link you will get Netlify's 404 page. This is
> because the pages that are not generated don't actually exist as they
> are actually a single page application so if you refesh this page you
> will get a 404 because the url for that page doesn't actually exist.
> By redirecting to the 404.html Nuxt will reload your page correctly in
> SPA fallback.
>
> The easiest way to fix this is by adding a generate property in your
> nuxt.config and setting fallback: true. Then it will fallback to the
> generated 404.html when in SPA mode instead of Netlify's 404 page.

References:

- https://nuxtjs.org/faq/netlify-deployment/
- https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/#fallback

Comment: Does nothing for me. Still get 404 refreshing any slug page.

Answer (score -2):

When you generate static pages, it produces directories and index.html in each one. How did  you expect to have it dynamic if you serve static HTML?

You have 2 solutions:

1. don't use `npm run generate`. Run nuxt on the server. Using this solution, you avoid ajax in browser. Instead, nuxt performs it and sends the HTML to the browser. Good for SEO.
2. have your web server (nginx) point all requests to `/index.html` - at that point, javascript takes over and it can correctly find the slug and query the products via ajax. Bad for SEO because you need to use ajax to get the content after page finishes loading.

Documentation and configuration about this can be found at nuxt's web.

Comment: RE: When you generate static pages, it produces directories and index.html in each one. How did you expect to have it dynamic if you serve static HTML?

During development it works just as expected, this is why -- I didn't realize what the built/generated product would look like in the end, until now.

RE: don't use npm run generate. Run nuxt on the server. Using this solution, you avoid ajax in browser. Instead, nuxt performs it and sends the HTML to the browser. Good for SEO.

Does this mean I should write a server.js, and within that have Nuxt handle requests?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, StackOverflow moderation team prevented me to reply. What you should do is run Nuxt in SSR mode. You write code as usual, when you deploy you run `npm run production` on the server. You use nginx to route requests to nuxt and to terminate SSL.